# File cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring, travis-ci

In my java spring application, I used a `data-set.sql` file to populate data for testing

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ConsultationWebApplication.class)
@Sql(scripts="requests-dataset.sql") 
@DirtiesContext(classMode= ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class StatisticsTest {

//bla
//bla
//bla
}'
```

But when i push my code to the repository, the **travis continuous integration**
complains with:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [ee/avok/consultation/service/requests-dataset.sql]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ee/avok/consultation/service/requests-dataset.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

The point is that, **the test runs and pass in the localhost, but it fails the CI**

It seems that the CI cannot find the file,but the file is in the test package.

Answer (score -2):

In my experience such errors occur when you are developing under Windows and the CI server works under Unix.

My guess is that you have named some folder within the path to your SQL file with an uppercase letter in Windows. Windows doesn't care for upper or lower case and finds the file in any case. Unix distinguishes between upper and lower case and thus does not find the file.

Search for an uppercase character somewhere in the path to your SQL file.